# Find all references to SpecificClass.SpecificMethod() in VS2015 with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm trying to find all the places where the Dispose() method of my class is called in a rather large solution. More precisely, I want every line of code where Dispose() is called on an instance of my class, or its derived class.

But when I select "Find usages", it'll find me every Dispose() call on every IDisposable implementation in my solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with ReSharper, and in my opinion at least one of them should be able to do it. I can't figure out how though.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper adds "Find Usages Advanced" to the context menu. I need to ask less and search more.